# Dynamic Title Tooltip for font awesome icon is not displaying in Angular

Tags: html, angular, tooltip

I am trying to add a dynamic string to the tooltip of the font awesome icon but somehow it is not displaying the value even the ng-reflect-title has value.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Below is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/icon-font-awesome-kqxkgk

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```html
<span>
    <fa name="cog" title="{{text}}"></fa>
    Text
</span>
```

And it should work.

Remember that title is used to show extra information about an element, and that information is shown as a tooltip text when the mouse is over the element.